# application not installed android 4.0 ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm having some problems with an application that is already on the market. Point is it worked perfectly on android 3.0 and previously, but on ICS the app gives the "application not installed" if tried to launch from the menu, but it works fine if launched from the market.
I know is a known bug but cant fix it yet.

this is the market link:
https://market.android.com/details?id=test.App1&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInRlc3QuQXBwMSJd

and this is the link to pastebin(the formatting was killing me, sorry for that):
http://pastebin.com/AsZ0bTrd

Comment: Did you transfer the file somehow? Or did you install it from market? Maybe the software isn't compatible with ICS, what app is it?

Comment: post your manifest.xml or your app.

Comment: added link to the app and to pastebin with the xml to the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue and I got an exception, that the permission for the external storage is wrong.

I took a look at your manifest and the only difference I found is that you have a closing tag for this permission but not for the others.

Try to remove the closing tag and close it directly...

Comment: Did as you said, but nothing changed (as i thought to be honest), thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the permission attribute you use in the application tag? I just saw that you have the permission there, too.

Comment: yep! that was the solution, seems the double permission screwed the whole app with ICS. Thanks alot!!